# Click event not working inside handlebar template

Tags: jquery, templates, handlebars.js

My Template is like this

```
{{#users}}
 <div id="userRoleInfo">
        <input type="hidden" id="userId" value="{{id}}" />
        <div class="label">
            <label>User permission</label>
        </div>

     <div class="user-item-right">
// I want to capture click event of this anchor tag
            <a href="#" class="updown-arrow" onClick="callUserDetail()" data-control="userBtn"><i class="icon-arrow-big"></i></a>
          </div>    

        {{#checkUser ../user.roleId roleId ../roles}}
            <div >Administrator</div>
        {{else}} 
            <select id="selRoleId" data-custom="true">                                                   
                    <option value="0" >Assign Role</option>

                {{#each roles}}
                    <option value="{{roleId}}">{{name}}</option>
                {{/each}}

            </select> 
        {{/checkUser}}

   </div>

 {{/users}}
```

This whole template is appended inside

```
 <div id="usersMgmtDiv" class="user-mngt-wrapper clearFix">
 </div>
```

I want to display user info when I click on anchor tag inside

```
  <div class="user-item-right">
```

function I have written for click event is like this

```
   japp.users.bindEdit = function () {

 if (jQuery('[data-control=userBtn]').size() === 0) {
    return;
 }

var self = japp;

jQuery('[data-control=userBtn]').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if(jQuery(this).is('.active')){
            self.users.hideUserBox(jQuery(this));
        } else {
            self.users.showUserBox(jQuery(this));
        }
    });
});
```

but its not going inside this function

**Update**

I tried to call using javascript method like

```
  function callUserDetail(){
japp.users.bindEdit();
}
```

But it takes 2 clicks to work this

Is this should work or is there other way to do this. Please let me know if more information is needed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
jQuery('[data-control=userBtn]').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).live('click', function (e) { /* ... */ });
});
```

There won't be any `[data-control=userBtn]` elements on the page when you try to iterate over them. Those `<a>`s won't exist until after you've added the filled in template to the page. Also, `live` was deprecated way back in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9 so you shouldn't be using it anymore, you should be using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Ideally, you'd have a known container that you'd put your template into. Then you would say:

```
$('#container').on('click', '[data-control=userBtn]', function(e) {
    // Deal with the click in here.
});
```

and throw the filled in template into `#container`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/PhtP3/

If you don't have such a container, then you could use the live-ish form of `on`:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-control=userBtn]', function(e) { ...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZaLnq/

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Its working perfect and up vote for nice explanation with examples